# Debug assertion failed when windows start

Tags: windows-7

My laptop is running on Win7 x64. When I start it is giving me error for c++

Below is the screenshot for error alert

[image: http://imgur.com/jUQBdFQ]

Comment: Is there anything in the event logs?

Answer (score 1):

Run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the crosshair from toolbar

[image: Process Explorer CrossHair]

and move it to the Error message. This will highlight the program which causes the error message. Now use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to disable it from startup.